# XML deserialization to object

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

So i've been trying to deserialize this xml file to some objects, its simple enough but it keeps returning null to the objects, the data that i need is stored inside the attributes of the element.

Here is the XML.

```
 <exchangerates xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" type="Valutakurser" author="Danmarks Nationalbank" refcur="DKK" refamt="1">
<dailyrates id="2020-10-20">
    <currency code="AUD" desc="Australske dollar" rate="442,98"/>
    <currency code="BGN" desc="Bulgarske lev" rate="380,53"/>
</dailyrates>
```

And this is the deserialisation code.

```
public static T DeserializeElement<T>(string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            T result;
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), new 
            XmlRootAttribute("exchangerates"));
            
            using (TextReader tr = new StringReader(filename))
            {
                result = (T)serializer.Deserialize(tr);
            }

            return result;
        }
        catch { throw; }
    }
```

And these are the objects

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
ElementName = "exchangerates",
DataType = "Valutakurser")]
[Serializable]
public class Valutakurser
{
    
    [XmlArray("dailyrates")]
    public DateTime Id { get; set; }
    public Currency Currency { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Currency
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public double Rate { get; set; }

    public Currency() { }
}
```

Currently I keep getting this error and everything returned null:

InvalidOperationException: For non-array types, you may use the following attributes: XmlAttribute, XmlText, XmlElement, or XmlAnyElement

Comment: is this a working example? there a several things not matching. I see uppercase properties but lowercase xml elements. the Rate property expects a double but the content of rate has a value with a colon in it instead of a dot. the Id expects a datetime but only a date is found in the xml. the xml has more attributes than that there are properties defined. and in the deserializer i see textreader tr = new STRINGreader? I suggest that you create an xsd for the message and use that as input for a tool like xsd.exe to generate the classes.

Comment: you are completely right about the colon instead of the dot, I completely oversaw this since I forgot that in xml it doesn't matter if its a dot or colon. I have fixed that part in the xml document

Comment: Don't forget that VS2019 can create classes from XML (and JSON).   Copy the XML to your clipboard, then in VS Edit/Paste Special/Paste XML as classes.  I've just tried this, and it says your XML is invalid !

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Valutakurser));
            Valutakurser valutakurser = (Valutakurser)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "exchangerates")]
    public class Valutakurser
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public DateTime id { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("dailyrates")]
        public DailyRates DalyRates { get; set; }
    }
    public class DailyRates
    {
        [XmlElement("currency")]
        public List<Currency> Currency { get; set; }
    }

    public class Currency
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string code { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string desc { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public double rate { get; set; }

        public Currency() { }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked out, I cannot believe i've been kinda close for almost a week now, feeling kinda stupid.